# graphically representing date sequences and durations in php

Tags: php, graph, charts

I have 2 arrays: one storing the beginning of actions and the second the durations. The beginnings are timestamps (descending order from the most recent) and the durations are in seconds, for instance the beginnings of a user logins and their durations. Something as:

$beginnings = array(1458945920,1458945657,1458940547,1458940444,1458940038,1458939783,1458939655);
$durations = array(154,253,4973,33,202,242,115);

I wish to represent those 2 arrays with a chart.

On the labels of the x-axis I wish to show the values of the beginnings, horizontally separated by each other proportionally to the difference between one beginning and the next.  On the y-axis, on the correspondence to the beginnings, I wish to show a bar as high as the duration value. I had a look at few charting libraries as pchart or phpchart, but in the examples I couldn't see anything like that. And I'm new to charting so I ask for a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Time-Duration Bar Chart]

The attached chart is created using a commercial charting library called [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com) using the code below.

```
<?php
require_once("../lib/phpchartdir.php");

$beginnings = array(1458945920,1458945657,1458940547,1458940444,1458940038,1458939783,1458939655); 
$durations = array(154,253,4973,33,202,242,115);

# Chart Image and Plotting Region
$c = new XYChart(800, 360);
$c->setPlotArea(70, 20, 700, 300, Transparent, -1, Transparent, 0xcccccc);

# X-Axis configuration
$c->xAxis->setColors(0x888888);
$c->xAxis->setTickDensity(75);
$c->xAxis->setMargin(10, 10);
$c->xAxis->setRounding(true, true);
$c->xAxis->setLabelStyle("arial.ttf", 10);

# Y-Axis configuration
$c->yAxis->setColors(Transparent);
$c->yAxis->setTickDensity(40);
$c->yAxis->setLabelStyle("arial.ttf", 10);
$c->yAxis->setTitle("Duration", "arialbd.ttf", 14, 0x555555);

# Bar Layer
$barLayerObj = $c->addBarLayer($durations, 0x6699bb);
$barLayerObj->setBorderColor(Transparent);
$barLayerObj->setXData(array_map(chartTime2, $beginnings));
$barLayerObj->setBarWidth(10);

# Output the chart
header("Content-type: image/png");
print($c->makeChart2(PNG));
?>
```

You can insert the chart in a web page just like a normal image:

```
<img src="create_chart.php">
```

where "create_chart.php" is the file that contains the above charting code.

Comment: Thanks, the library looks interesting.

Comment: However, I tried your example of my localhost. I use Xampp 3.2.1 on Windows. phpinfo outputs

PHP Version => 5.5.11
extension_dir => C:\xampp\php\ext => C:\xampp\php\ext

I added extension=phpchartdir550.dll (before I tried also with extension=phpchartdir550nts.dll) to php.ini and copied all .dll in the extension directory. I restarted Xampp. I even restarted windows.
But I always get the error:
---
 Error Loading ChartDirector for PHP Extension

It appears this PHP system has not loaded the ChartDirector extension by using an extension statement in the PHP configuration ...
---
any idea?

Comment: never mind.. I though my Xampp was 64bit bit it's 32, I downloaded the correct one and it works

Comment: I can see the demos now but still can't manage to visualize the chart in a web page. What's wrong with
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test ChartDirector</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="create_chart.php">
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: Can you see the chart if you directly access "create_chart.php" (just enter http://localhost/ChartDirector/phpdemo/create_chart.php in the browser address bar)? Note that the code uses require_once("../lib/phpchartdir.php");. Depending on where is "create_chart.php" and where is "phpchartdir.php", you may need to adjust the path to fit your directory structure. If you cannot see the chart, please let me know of the error message. If you cannot see the error message, please include the line "ini_set('display_errors',1);" before all the code in "create_chart.php" to enable PHP error reporting.

Comment: thanks, it works after I moved ChartDirector files to a different directory.